# AWS stream lookup fails with GUID

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup a distribution service and a streaming service with AWS

**file key**

```
1cbbb66f-c72d-40cb-a0b6-2303aa33ed75
```

If I use the [stream tester](http://d1k5ny0m6d4zlj.cloudfront.net/diag/CFStreamingDiag.html)

I get the error message

```
NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

But if I hit the url

```
https://myurl.cloudfront.net/1cbbb66f-c72d-40cb-a0b6-2303aa33ed75
```

I am able to download the file and play it

**More file info**

Content Type: application/octet-stream

Permission: Everyone: Open/Download

I changed the guid name to t15 (random choice) and it worked. Why is guid key look up failing for streaming service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file extension in the bucket. This doesnt make sense to me as the key does not include the extension, but I guess the logic is AWS isnt sure what to do with the file if there is not an extension